# Retrieving ordered data from firebase real-time database Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have a real-time firebase database that looks like this.

[image: DataBase Snapshot]

There are many elements along with 3 shown in the image on the same level as those 3.
What I want to do is fetch them in Kotlin based on parameter **OrderCount**.
Therefore when I fetch I want **Dragon Fruit** to be **1st**, **Cherimoya** to be **2nd**,**Ackee** to be **3rd** and so on.
Based on Stackoverflow and other resources this is what I tried.

```
            val refFeatured1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/all_items/Exotic_Fruits")
                .orderByChild("OrderCount")
            refFeatured1.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                    Log.d("LoadingActivity", "Error in Fetching all items data : ${p0}")
                    return
                }
                override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                    Log.d("LoadingActivity", "${p0}")
            }
        })
```

The result of the following query gives me other elements.
This result does not change even if I change the parameter of **orderByChild**.

This is the [code](https://github.com/aniketbote/food-grain-app/blob/popular/FF/app/src/main/java/com/example/farmfresh/Activities/LoadingActivity.kt) for getting the result.
What I also want is getting only the first 5 results after ordering.
Will **limitToFirst(5)** attribute be used to achieve this or is there any other way.
The same code when I tried from python gives me perfect result:
The code is:

```
ref = db.reference('all_items/Exotic_Fruits').order_by_child("OrderCount").limit_to_first(5)
refData = ref.get()
```

Comment: What doesn't work about the code that is **in** your question? For example: which of the `Log` statement prints something different than you expected?

Comment: The Log statement that prints the data snapshot. ie."Log.d("LoadingActivity", "${p0}")".

Comment: What does it print? And what did you expect?

Comment: It returns me a data snapshot of an incorrect order. However, when I iterate the data snapshot over a for loop it gives me the correct order. For eg I get elements starting with element "Kiwano" but when I iterate over the data snapshot the first element which it prints is dragon fruit which is what I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you request ordered data from Firebase, you get a `DataSnapshot` with the results. For each matching node, that contains:

1. The value of the node
2. The key of the node
3. The position of the node, relative to the other results.

When you request the value of the node as a whole (by calling `value` or as you do by printing it), the results are converted into a `Map` object. In a map there is no order between the keys, so the ordering information gets lost.

To maintain the information on the order of the results, you need to loop over the `DataSnapshot.children` list.

```
val refFeatured1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/all_items/Exotic_Fruits")
    .orderByChild("OrderCount")
refFeatured1.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d("LoadingActivity", "Error in Fetching all items data : ${p0}")
        return
    }
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for (snapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
            Log.d("LoadingActivity", "${snapshot}")
        }
    }
})
```

Also see the Firebase documentation of [read lists with a value listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#kotlin+ktx_2), where I got the loop from.